# How to trigger the $routeprovider while editing url

Tags: angularjs, routes, ng-view

I can  trigger the $routeprovider while refreshing the addressbar.I want to  trigger the routeprovider while editing the url in addressbar.(http://localhost/Angular/samples/#/home/grouping).I want edit this url like(http://localhost/Angular/samples/#/home/split).while refreshing i can trigger the $routeProviderReference.but i can't trigger while edit and click the addressbar.

$routeProviderReference.when("/" + $rootScope.subRoute.templateUrl, {

```
        templateUrl: $rootScope.subRoute.templateUrl + ".html",

        resolve: ["$q", "$rootScope", function ($q, $rootScope) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            require([

               $rootScope.subRoute.templateUrl

            ], function () {

                $rootScope.$apply(function () {

                    deferred.resolve();
                });

            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }]

    });

};
```

Can anyone please suggest me

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question so that it will be more clear

Comment: I have elaborated the question

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to capture a live change in your address bar, that will **not** be possible because the address bar does not lie within your HTML document and your code will not have access to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.While refreshing i have call my method.Then i can trigger the $routeprovider.while clicking the addressbar i can call my method in $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (args) {

       // $scope.loadSample();


    }).but i can't trigger the $routeprovider.Can you please suggest me